# Spring Boot 3.1 OAuth2 Security Filter not working on actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can't seem to allow "admin" role access to actuator endpoints.
Boot 3.1
OAuth2 Keycloak

JWT token is authenticated in debugger with correct role.

This is a microservice registered to Eureka, connected to Spring Cloud Configuration Server with Spring Cloud Bus (RabbitMQ) as refresh implementation.

I am now hooking up security using OAuth2 Keycloak implementation as a resource server.
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server

The Rest controllers are being protected correctly. However, I am attempting to secure the actuator endpoints to authenticated user with "admin" role. Note I have overridden the default actuator base-path and the actuator is on a different port than app.

The stack trace is misleading. Not sure why I show mismatch source in debugger. But the issue appears to be in the AuthoritiesAuthorizationManager (spring-security-core:6.1.1)
return not granted even though there is a matching role.

```
    private boolean isGranted(Authentication authentication, Collection<String> authorities) {
        return authentication != null && this.isAuthorized(authentication, authorities);
    }
    private boolean isAuthorized(Authentication authentication, Collection<String> authorities) {
        Iterator var3 = this.getGrantedAuthorities(authentication).iterator();

        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority;
        do {
            if (!var3.hasNext()) {
                return false;
            }

            grantedAuthority = (GrantedAuthority)var3.next();
        } while(!authorities.contains(grantedAuthority.getAuthority()));

        return true;
    }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Properties

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: true
    roles: admin
  server:
    port: 8690
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
      base-path: /${spring.application.name}/actuator
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: "http://localhost:${env.idp.port}/realms/osint-realm"
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs

jwt:
  token:
    converter:
      resource-id: osint-keycloak-client
      # Extract the value of this field from the access token and use it as the identifier for the authenticated user.
      principal-attribute: preferred_username

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
```

pom:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2022.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Filter

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class GlobalSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    private final KeycloakJwtTokenConverter keycloakJwtTokenConverter;

    public GlobalSecurityConfiguration(TokenConverterProperties properties) {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        this.keycloakJwtTokenConverter = new KeycloakJwtTokenConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter, properties);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/" + appName + "/actuator/**").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        );

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(authorize -> authorize
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(keycloakJwtTokenConverter))
        );

        http.sessionManagement(session -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        );
        return http.build();
    }
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class GlobalSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    private final KeycloakJwtTokenConverter keycloakJwtTokenConverter;

    public GlobalSecurityConfiguration(TokenConverterProperties properties) {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        this.keycloakJwtTokenConverter = new KeycloakJwtTokenConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter, properties);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/" + appName + "/actuator/**").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        );

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(authorize -> authorize
            .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(keycloakJwtTokenConverter))
        );

        http.sessionManagement(session -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        );
        return http.build();
    }
```

public class KeycloakJwtTokenConverter implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {

```
private static final String RESOURCE_ACCESS = "resource_access";
private static final String ROLES = "roles";
protected static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
private final TokenConverterProperties properties;

public KeycloakJwtTokenConverter(
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter,
    TokenConverterProperties properties) {
    this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
    this.properties = properties;
}

@Override
public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt jwt) {
    Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority> accesses = Optional.of(jwt)
        .map(token -> token.getClaimAsMap(RESOURCE_ACCESS))
        .map(claimMap -> (Map<String, Object>) claimMap.get(properties.getResourceId()))
        .map(resourceData -> (Collection<String>) resourceData.get(ROLES))
        .stream()
        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + role))
        .distinct();

    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream
        .concat(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(), accesses)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    String principalClaimName = properties.getPrincipalAttribute()
        .map(jwt::getClaimAsString)
        .orElse(jwt.getClaimAsString(JwtClaimNames.SUB));

    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, principalClaimName);
}
```

07:57:54.866 [http-nio-8690-exec-1] TRACE o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Sending JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@965b938c, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_email, ROLE_[admin], SCOPE_profile]] to access denied handler since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98)

```
[![AuthoritiesAuthorizationManager][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQk4i.png
```

Comment: You should provide us with your KeycloakJwtTokenConverter,

Comment: If you throw a breakpoint in `ExceptionTranslationFilter` are you able to see where in the `RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager` it is getting thrown?

Comment: I debugged into AuthoritiesAuthorizationManager. At this point I can see matching roles. The strange thing is the source doesn't match so the loop doesn't break with granted = true even though JWT is authenticated and there is a matching role to the authorities.

Comment: Your Keycloak roles mapping to Spring authorities is probably bugged: see `ROLE_[admin]` in the logs (shouldn't it be `ROLE_admin`?). So I suggest you really consider my first comment and add your `KeycloakJwtTokenConverter` source (instead of `GlobalSecurityConfiguration` second occurence, for instance)

Comment: Converter added. Debug image added. Roles are correct, see image. ROLE_ is prepended to both the keycloak authorities and the security filter.

Comment: The basic issue is with the JwtTokenConverter creating one SimpleGrantedAuthority with a string role of "ROLE_" and the list of roles from the JWT. This string will not match the filter ever because new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + "admin") resolves to a string ROLE_[admin, user, actuator.....] Working on a fix

Answer (score 0):

The JWT converter I patterned after [KeycloakJwtTokenConverter](https://github.com/Pask423/keycloak-springboot/blob/master/base-integration-spring-boot-3/src/main/java/org/pcs/springboot/keycloak/security/KeycloakJwtTokenConverter.java)

had a bad assumption in that mapped role would only be a list of 1.

```
.map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + role))
```

Correction to include multiple roles used to compare to requestMatchers in a SecurityFilterChain

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimNames;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

//https://github.com/Pask423/keycloak-springboot/blob/master/base-integration-spring-boot-3/src/main/java/org/pcs/springboot/keycloak/security/KeycloakJwtTokenConverter.java
public class KeycloakJwtTokenConverter implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ACCESS = "resource_access";
    private static final String ROLES = "roles";
    protected static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
    private final TokenConverterProperties properties;

    public KeycloakJwtTokenConverter(
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter,
        TokenConverterProperties properties) {
        this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt jwt) {
        List<Collection<String>> roleResources = Optional.of(jwt)
            .map(token -> token.getClaimAsMap(RESOURCE_ACCESS))
            .map(claimMap -> (Map<String, Object>) claimMap.get(properties.getResourceId()))
            .map(resourceData -> (Collection<String>) resourceData.get(ROLES))
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        roleResources.forEach(role -> role.forEach(roleValue -> simpleGrantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + roleValue))));

        Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority> accesses = simpleGrantedAuthorities.stream().distinct();

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream
            .concat(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(), accesses)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        String principalClaimName = properties.getPrincipalAttribute()
            .map(jwt::getClaimAsString)
            .orElse(jwt.getClaimAsString(JwtClaimNames.SUB));

        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, principalClaimName);
    }
}
```